# Problem: Nested function(handler) in AppleScript?

Tags: applescript

How can I put a handler/function in another handler/function?

I write a sample code below and got error:

**"Expected "end"  but found "on""**

Why?

```
Dialog1()

on Dialog1()
    display dialog "Hello World!"
    Dialog2()

        on Dialog2()
            display dialog "Welcome to AppleScript"
        end Dialog2 

end Dialog1
```

Comment: AppleScript doesn't support nested handler(s). It states [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_about_handlers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH206-CJBIDBJH): _" ...you can not nest a handler definition within another handler (although a script object defined in a handler can contain other handlers)."_. See [this example](https://paste.ee/p/DP9Vr) which is somewhat analogous to a function inside a function in JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now ic why. and thanks for your solution. :D

Comment: I'm not sure what you're ultimate goal here is, but it's worth looking at this old link — https://www.apeth.net/matt/unm/asph.html — which shows you the kinds of things you can do with AppleScript handlers. Very cool stuff.

Comment: Thanks @Ted Wrigley. the link you showed is very good. I really like it.

Answer (score 0):

You were real close.  This should work for you.

```
Dialog1()

on Dialog1()
    display dialog "Hello World!"
    Dialog2()
end Dialog1

on Dialog2()
    display dialog "Welcome to AppleScript"
end Dialog2
```

Or this

```
Dialog1()
Dialog2()

on Dialog1()
    display dialog "Hello World!"
end Dialog1

on Dialog2()
    display dialog "Welcome to AppleScript"
end Dialog2
```

You can also wrap everything up inside of a script object and then just run the script object..

```
run twoDialogs

script twoDialogs
    Dialog1()
    Dialog2()

    on Dialog1()
        display dialog "Hello World!"
    end Dialog1

    on Dialog2()
        display dialog "Welcome to AppleScript"
    end Dialog2
end script
```

Comment: It seems AppleScript doesn't support nested handler.  

In contrast, in javascript or some else,  it can put function inside function.

Comment: very thanks for your solutions. :D Plus the reason from @RobC, perfect!